# Linked data - RDF output format

Tags: java, rdf, jena, linked-data

I'm trying to convert and join rdf

I have doubts that RDF format priority order how to decided

[This is what I created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsSWp.png)

[This is what I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R24Jb.png)

I want to make films resource contain director instead of currently appearance

(films is in outermost)

I use jena API to write this program

My example code is:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){

    Model m=ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    m.setNsPrefix("LODQL", "http://lodql.com.tw/");
    Resource subject=m.createResource("http://lodql.com.tw/film/1");
    Resource object=m.createResource("http://lodql.com.tw/director/1");

    Property p=m.createProperty("http://lodql.com.tw/","directorBy");
    Property p2=m.createProperty("http://lodql.com.tw/","director");

    m.add(m.createStatement(subject, p, object));
    m.add(m.createStatement(object, p2, subject));

    File file = new File("./dirTest.rdf");
    BufferedWriter fw = null;
    fw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new 
    FileOutputStream(file, false), "UTF8"));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fw, true);
    m.write(out,"RDF/XML");

}
```

example output is director in outermost, but I want films in outer

Can I decided what resource in outermost?

Thanks very much!!

Comment: Please provide your code and/or configuration as text in the question (code blocks), not as a screenshot.

Comment: For RDF the order of statements does not matter - it is a graph. If in your case the order (what is "outermost") matters then the question is why. Normally you would consume this RDF/XML using RDF parser for which, again, the order does not matter. Do you have in mind a different use for this data?

Comment: yes , I know the order does not matter, but I want to create a main resource and complemantary resource present

Comment: LDFileWriter is not part of Apache Jena.

Comment: sorry , this is class writing by myself, I have been edited! thx

Comment: The output writers in jena are customizable.  See e.g., https://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/rdfxml_howto.html.